# Finding a basis for a particular subspace with Dot Product restrictions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find the basis of the subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ that consists of all vectors perpendicular to both $[1, -2, 0, 3]$ and $[0,2,1,3]$.

My teacher applies dot product:
Let $[w,x,y,z]$ be the vectors in the subspace. Then,

$w-2x+3z=0$ and
$2x+y+3z=0$

So, she solves the system and get the following:

$\text{Subspace}=\{ t[-1,-1/2,1,0] + s[-6,-3/2,0,1]|t,s \ \text{are in} \  \Bbb R\}$.

But, I do the following:

I isolate $w$ and $y$:
$w=2x-3z$ and
$y=-2x-3z$.

I replace them : $\text{Subspace}= \{ [2x-3z,x,-2x-3z,z]|x,z \ \text{are in} \ \Bbb R\} = \operatorname{span}\{[2,1,-2,0],[-3,0,-3,1]\}$.

I set up a system of linear equation to see if $[-3,0,-3,1]$ is a linear combination of the vectors in my teacher's answer. However, it is not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is anyone thinking about this?

Answer (score 1):

In order for $[-3,0,-3,1]= \alpha [-1,-1/2,1,0]+\beta[-6,-3/2,0,1]$, you'll need $\beta=1$ because of the 4th entry, and you'll need $\alpha=-3$ because of the third entry. Then check if the following holds:
$$
    [-3,0,-3,1] = -3[-1,-1/2,1,0]+[-6,-3/2,0,1].
$$
It looks like it checks to me.